# Interface containing function and data class. Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, design-patterns, interface, data-class

I am new to Kotlin and I came up with question about interface which contains function, also data classes like input and output. Take a look to example below.

```
interface SomeInterfaceName {
fun SomeFunction(input: Input): Output
}

data class Input() {
val inputField: String
}

data class Output() {
val outputField: String
}
```

Is this correct? Are there any patterns, which says that we cannot do it? Thank you in advance for responses

Answer (score 2):

`data class`es must be initialized via their constructor, thus your declarations should rather look something along the lines of:

```kotlin
data class Input(val inputField: String)
data class Output(val outputField: String)
```

In general function names in Kotlin should be written in camelCase most of the time.

```kotlin
interface SomeInterfaceName {
    fun someFunction(input: Input): Output
}
```

Other than that, I don't see anything wrong with the design approach itself.
In my opinion, it's good when an interface is in control of its input and output types.
For example, lending on Clean Architecture design patterns, you may end up with something along the following:

```kotlin
data class TickTodoCommand(val todoId: Long)
sealed interface TickTodoResult {
    object Success: TickTodoResult
    data class Failure(val reason: String): TickTodoResult
}

interface TickTodoUseCase {
    operator fun invoke(command: TickTodoCommand): TickTodoResult
}

class TickTodoService(todoGateway: TodoGateway): TickTodoUseCase {
    override fun invoke(command: TickTodoCommand): TickTodoResult {
        val todo = todoGateway.find(command.todoId)
            ?: return TickTodoResult.Failure("Todo does not exist!")
        
        todo.ticked = true
        
        todoGateway.save(todo)

        return TickTodoResult.Success
    }
}

class TodoController(private val tickTodo: TickTodoUseCase) {
    fun tick(id: Long) {
        tickTodo(TickTodoCommand(id))
    }
}
```